# Maximum call stack size exceeded error only in debugging environment

Tags: javascript, recursion, ram, vscode-debugger

I have this recursive function (shown below) with base cases that has been working fine for the past couple months. I haven't changed this piece of code in months but when I try debugging my code through VSCode I am now randomly getting a `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` error. I even commented out the code that calls the function and it still outputs the same error.

However it runs fine when I execute the code in my bash terminal or in my production environment. Is it because my debugger isn't allocating enough RAM?

```js
async function formatConversation(convoArr, index, conversation, isBot, depth, preset) {
  if (index <= 0 || depth == 10) {
    return convoArr[index];
  } else {
    const entity = isBot ? 'Bot:' : 'Human:'
    conversation = await formatConversation(convoArr, index - 1, conversation, !isBot, depth + 1, preset)
    return `${conversation}\n${entity} ${convoArr[index]}`;
  }
}
```

Comment: *"I even commented out the code that calls the function"*: if this function **isn't** called, and you still get the error, then the problem can't be this function, right?

Comment: I commented it where it's being called:
`let formattedConvo = ''//await formatConversation(convo, convo.length - 1, '', false, 0, preset)`. 
But I'm still getting the error: 
`Uncaught RangeError RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at formatConversation (/Users/dhruvpatel/projectname/util/helpers.js:218:34) at formatConversation (/Users/dhruvpatel/projectname/util/helpers.js:223:26)`

Could just be that my debugger is corrupt?

Comment: The stack trace should help you find the cause.

Comment: It sounds like the function is called elsewhere as well